# Why are standard mobile dimensions leaving so much real-estate on the sides?

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

For instance most @media calls will say the design is for a 480px width but then they set the containers for 360px? Is their a specific reason why so much room is being un accounted for? Example of 320 which sets container widths of 260 and 480 which sets container widths to 360 below.

```
/*  #Mobile (Portrait)
```

================================================== */

```
/* Note: Design for a width of 320px */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .container,
    .container.floated { width: 260px; }

    .container .columns,
    .container .column { margin: 0; }
    .container .floated { float: left; padding: 0 30px; }
    .floated.sidebar { position: relative; }

    .container .one.column,
    .container .one.columns,
    .container .one.floated,
    .container .two.columns,
    .container .two.floated,
    .container .three.columns,
    .container .three.floated,
    .container .four.columns,
    .container .four.floated,
    .container .five.columns,
    .container .five.floated,
    .container .six.columns,
    .container .six.floated,
    .container .seven.columns,
    .container .seven.floated,
    .container .eight.columns,
    .container .eight.floated,
    .container .nine.columns,
    .container .nine.floated,
    .container .ten.columns,
    .container .ten.floated,
    .container .eleven.columns,
    .container .eleven.floated,
    .container .twelve.columns,
    .container .twelve.floated,
    .container .thirteen.columns,
    .container .thirteen.floated,
    .container .fourteen.columns,
    .container .fourteen.floated,
    .container .fifteen.columns,
    .container .fifteen.floated,
    .container .sixteen.columns,
    .container .sixteen.floated,
    .container .one-third.column,
    .container .two-thirds.column { width: 260px; }


    /* Offsets */
    .container .offset-by-one,
    .container .offset-by-two,
    .container .offset-by-three,
    .container .offset-by-four,
    .container .offset-by-five,
    .container .offset-by-six,
    .container .offset-by-seven,
    .container .offset-by-eight,
    .container .offset-by-nine,
    .container .offset-by-ten,
    .container .offset-by-eleven,
    .container .offset-by-twelve,
    .container .offset-by-thirteen,
    .container .offset-by-fourteen,
    .container .offset-by-fifteen { padding-left: 0; }


    /* Pricing Tables */
    .five-tables .pricing-table,
    .four-tables .pricing-table,
    .three-tables .pricing-table,
    .two-tables .pricing-table { width: 260px; }

}
```

/* #Mobile (Landscape)
================================================== */

```
/* Note: Design for a width of 480px */

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .container { width: 360px; }

    .container .columns,
    .container .column { margin: 0; }
    .container .floated { float: left; padding: 0 30px; }
    .floated.sidebar { position: relative; }

    .container .one.column,
    .container .one.columns,
    .container .one.floated,
    .container .two.columns,
    .container .two.floated,
    .container .three.columns,
    .container .three.floated,
    .container .four.columns,
    .container .four.floated,
    .container .five.columns,
    .container .five.floated,
    .container .six.columns,
    .container .six.floated,
    .container .seven.columns,
    .container .seven.floated,
    .container .eight.columns,
    .container .eight.floated,
    .container .nine.columns,
    .container .nine.floated,
    .container .ten.columns,
    .container .ten.floated,
    .container .eleven.columns,
    .container .eleven.floated,
    .container .twelve.columns,
    .container .twelve.floated,
    .container .thirteen.columns,
    .container .thirteen.floated,
    .container .fourteen.columns,
    .container .fourteen.floated,
    .container .fifteen.columns,
    .container .fifteen.floated,
    .container .sixteen.columns,
    .container .sixteen.floated,
    .container .one-third.column,
    .container .two-thirds.column { width: 360px; }

    /* Pricing Tables */
    .five-tables .pricing-table,
    .four-tables .pricing-table,
    .three-tables .pricing-table,
    .two-tables .pricing-table { width: 360px; }

}
```

I'm just wondering if I am missing something really important before I go and re-adjust everything.. I've seen it in almost all of the standard settings that I've been working with, and I feel like you don't need to have that much width un accounted for..

Comment: These styles look like a part of some kind of grid system that is set up with fixed widths.

If you want something fluid, you should simply check out some other grid system :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no real reason why it's happening.  I think that if you are using a grid framework they've just made the decision to give you a lot of margin for your content, even on a small screen.

Now from what you've posted I think that those margins are way too big.  But since it's CSS you can change whatever you want to.  Just set up your own media query that sets the containers to whatever you want (I usually do a margin of about 10px on mobile sized devices).  But it's up to you.

Again there's no real reason why this is happening except that someone somewhere decided it for the framework you're using.  I know others such as Twitter Bootstrap have margins of about 10px on mobile sizes.

I don't think there's anything standard in the examples you shared. I would daresay that it's very un-standard to have that much real-estate on the sides.

Comment: Awesome thanks guys, I think I just was just slightly doubting myself on this project, and over analyzing everything.. I gutted the whole set up and ran with my own widths. Thanks again for the comments!